# Does FileStream.Seek() transfer data across the wire?

Tags: network-programming, filestream, smb, random-access, fileserver

I need to access random parts of a very large file across the network.  (SMB protocol)

- Does FileStream.Seek() actually read the data (copying down the entire file in the process) when doing a fs.Seek()?
- Is there anything I can do to reduce or buffer this IO?

My intent is to poll the end of a large file for changes, and if they exist read forward from a bookmark (fixed position) in .NET.

Comment: Have you found your answer? I'm interested to hear the answer. My guess is, this will be system's dependant. Basically SMB provides `seek` operation, but it depends whether .NET & OS will utilize it or not. On Windows you may get the correct `seek` behavior.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is going to operate only on local data in a stream data type. That the FileStream is "cached" locally does not mean that you are performing a `.seek()` on data on some remote filesystem, but instead downloading it as a stream onto your local machine. Please see this link (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx) for more about FileStream over network.

Comment: Does this apply to regular .NET programming, not specific to SQL integrations?  (Command line application)